# SQlite.When i clicked my save button,without insert any data then its show error,apps not open..but when i insert all field then its working well

Tags: android, sqlite

When I use String data, if I use if condition then it works, but for integer its doesn't work. For string I use

Then it works, but for integer its not working. What do I need to use for integer?

```
{
    if(mtitle.length()!=0){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        DataTemp dt = new DataTemp(mtitle, mdate, mnote);
        mf.addToTable(dt);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Successfully insert!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your table create command? The issue is with your create table query. Your table columns data type may not accepting the data you are inserting into it.

Comment: more over the above code you have posted will not add any row to your table because you are starting another activity before inserting data to table.

Comment: thanks.in my project everything is ok.my question was ,i want to add checked if user input in all field then data will be saved other wise i want to show a tost message ,like please insert all input field.how can i checked this?

Comment: String s="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+TAB_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+TAB_TITLE+" INTEGER, "+TAB_DATE+" INTEGER, "+TAB_NOTE+" INTEGER)";

        db.execSQL(s);

Comment: here is your answer in your question. Your table accepts only integer type data. You have mentioned all fields to accept INTEGER datatype.

Comment: You can check all fields by using if and else if conditions that the required fields are empty or null.

Comment: i want to checked it,if all input field user give value then its store data,otherwise its show a toast message,now tell me how can i do this.

Comment: i did.but not working.                                                                                                              check   if (mtitle!=0){

                    DataTemp dt = new DataTemp(mtitle, mdate, mnote);
                    mf.addToTable(dt);
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Successfully insert!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

Comment: posting it as answer, but before that if you post your actual requirement on basis of your code then it will be more clear to me

Comment: can you please tell me the data type of "mtitle, mdate, mnote" variables

Comment: ok.thanks now tell me how can i solved this.see my all mainactivity code.

Comment: int mtitle=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
                int  mdate=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
          
                int  mnote=mtitle+mdate;

Comment: are you inserting only integer values to these editText fields?

Comment: see all required code.()

Comment: int mtitle=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
                int  mdate=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    
                int  mnote=mtitle+mdate;

                if (mtitle!=0){

                    DataTemp dt = new DataTemp(mtitle, mdate, mnote);
                    mf.addToTable(dt);
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Insert all fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

Comment: review the question edit

Comment: I DON'T understand.can you solved this.

Comment: as per your requirement before calling addToTable all fields are checked. You can add more if statements to check other fields or to validate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you to check the editText fields are empty or contains some data. If your insert query is working this code will work.

```
public void insertData() {
        if ((e1.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
            // show toast to enter some data in first field.
            return;
        } else if ((e2.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
            // show toast to enter some data in first field
            return;
        }
            int mtitle = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
            int mdate = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
            int mnote = mtitle + mdate;
       if (mtitle == 0) {
            // show toast that mtitle field cant be zero
        } else if (mtitle != 0) {
                DataTemp dt = new DataTemp(mtitle, mdate, mnote);
                mf.addToTable(dt);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data inserted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks but same problem,not work,when clicked save button its show this error message

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: androidsqlite.com.sqlite30january, PID: 4237
                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                      at androidsqlite.com.sqlite30january.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)

Comment: you must have inserted some null value to your edittext. updating the code use that

Comment: code updated now you will not get this exception. Make sure your editText contains only integer type data.

Comment: from where i sure my editText contains only integer value.in al field i did all is integer.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: androidsqlite.com.sqlite30january, PID: 5372
                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                      at androidsqlite.com.sqlite30january.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)

Comment: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: can please post your activity code now. You are parsing non integer value to int.

Comment: see,,i send it as answer for sending all together

Comment: dude can you please copy my answer and add this to your code and call the same to your button onclick. and remove your code inside the button onClick

Comment: thanks a lot dear.many many thanks.its worked properly.where you from dear.are you student?.